# Targeting parent's router-outlet from child component in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Since Angular 2 Router was frequently updated, the old questions for this topic are no longer valid. I have been searching for a solution to this problem and I have yet to find one...

So, my problem is targeting parent's component router-outlet from a child component.

For example, we have an AppComponent like this one (root of our app) :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import {HeaderComponent}  from './header.component';
import {LibraryComponent}  from './library.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <header></header>
  <library></library>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,HeaderComponent,LibraryComponent],
  providers: []
 })
export class AppComponent {

}
```

And HeaderComponent looks like this :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector:'header',
template:'<a routerLink="test" routerLinkActive="active">go to TEST</a>',
   directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class HeaderComponent{}
```

The main part in my app.routes looks like this:

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
 {
  path: 'test',
  component: TestComponent
 }
];
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? 
When I click the link to "test", a new "test" div is created (I assume this is because of the selector in TestComponent) while the router-outlet remains empty.

Another question I also have is, why do I have to import the ROUTER_DIRECTIVES and also supply it to the directives in the child component HeaderComponent, if I have already done so in the parent component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you update your router link as below.

```
'<a [routerLink]="['../test']" routerLinkActive="active">go to TEST</a>'
```

if test is root you can do a absolute navigation
   'go to TEST

`RouterLink` accepts an array of commands as a value when used with '[]'.

you can also change route to be like
 'go to TEST'

`routerLink` is a directive and all directives used in a component has to provide in component metadata inside directives property. 
`ROUTER_DIRECTIVE` is a constant in `@angular/router` package which gives you array of relevant directive and routerLink is one of them.  Hence by using that you add routerLink directive in that array. You could(I am not sure if imported in router package) can pass just routerLink in that array and it will work.

For more details see [official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Comment: Parent is actually `[routerLink]="['../test']"`. If the parent is the root, then you can also use `[routerLink]="['/test']"`. You alsoneed to add `[]` around `routerLink` otherwise `"['/test']"` won't be interpreted as array, but as string which doesn't work with `[]`. `routerLink` supports a path as string, but only without `['']` like `routerLink="/test"`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for making this a better answer. are this changes in recent upgrade or i missed the it in doc. specifically relative navigation support from current route and string attribute `routerLink="/test"`

Comment: As far as I remember these path prefixes were supported in all routers (I'm using Angular2 since late alpha). Actually I only found out about passing strings directly very recently. I don't know if this was supported earlier.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but this still does not work. I have changed it to [routerLink]="['../test']" and it still createas a new "test" div while router-outlet remains empty. The root of our application is AppComponent, which has 2 child components,library and header, and in header I did change the routerLink to what you said, but it still doesn't work and I do not know why.

Comment: I tried also [routerLink]="['/test']", but the result is still the same, i will try to explore the docs to see if I find anything.

Comment: So I think that what I am seeing is actually a glitch, I am currently working on a desktop app with electron and that may be the cause of the glitch. I will accept the top answer as the right one.