# angular 2 display html content of inner child component in router outlet defined in base component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

I am working on sample application and have different components and child components

Following is the way route is configured in the application

Mainroute.ts:

```
export const routes: Routes = [   
    { path: '', redirectTo:'HomePage', pathMatch:'full' },   
    {
        path: 'HomePage', component: HomeComponent,
        children: [

            {
                path: 'component1-path', component: component1
                children: [
                    { path: 'component-innerchild1-path', component: component-child1},
                    { path: 'component-innerchild2-path', component: component-child2},
                    { path: 'component-innerchild3-path', component: component-child3}
                ]
            },

            { path: 'component2-child-path', component: component2},
            { path: 'component3-child-path', component: component3}
        ]
    },      
    { path: 'component3-path', component: component3},
    { path: '*', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

HomeComponent.ts :

```
This is Home page component
<a routerLink="component1-path">child component</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

component1page.html :  I am calling the html page in component1.ts file

```
This is component1 page  
<a routerLink="component-innerchild1-path">inner child component</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Component-child1page.html : I am calling the html page component1-child1.ts file

```
this is component1's inner child
```

When i run the page i am able to display the content of "Component-child1page.html" in routeroutlet defined in component1page.html page. 
I would like to display the content of "Component-child1page.html" when it is clicked in the "HomeComponent" html page. Is it possible to display the content in another routeroutlet?

**What i have tried:**
I have tried by providing the name attribute to routeroutlet in homepage html page

```
<router-outlet name="displayinnerchild"></router-outlet>
```

I have used the "outlet" property in Mainroute file as below to redirect to outlet in homepage but It didnt work :

```
{ path: 'component-innerchild1-path', component: component-child1, outlet: 'displayinnerchild'},
```

looked into the below link but didn't find much help

[Targeting parent's router-outlet from child component in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470032/targeting-parents-router-outlet-from-child-component-in-angular-2)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is it a child route of component1 if you want to display it in the router-outlet of the home page? Make it a child of the home route. As simple as that.

Comment: Isn't it `router-outlet` and not `routeroutlet`?

Comment: Thanks @Chrillewoodz,  Updated the question

Comment: @JBNizet , naviagtion of application is Homepage-> component1->componentchild. instead of display data in component1 router-outlet I want it to be displayed in Homepage router-outlet

Comment: I don't see what the navigation has to do with this. Nothing prevents you from adding a link into any route pointing to any other route.